# Geometry Node Attribute Unusable on Density (Shader Nodes)

Tags: shaders, geometry-nodes, shader-nodes, custom-attributes

I've found something weird. I have an Fac Attribute in my geometry nodes (it's a simple gradient). When I use it in Shader Nodes, it works, but not for the density value on volume absorbtion or volume scatter. Can you try on your side and tell me if you have the same result ?

Here is my shader node setup (with a standard Gradient texture) :
[image: blender node setup with simple gradient as volume density]

It gives this result : (correct)

[image: blender result with the above node setup]

Here, you can see what my Fac attribute (from Geometry Nodes) look on the surface (for demonstration) :
[image: same blender node setup, with attribute directly connected on surface]
[image: blender result with above shader node setup]

But, if i connect this same Fac on the density, it's like the Fac is full white :
[image: same blender node setup, with attribute Fac connected to the density]
[image: blender render from above node setup]

**So. few Questions :**

- **I am the only one to have this issue ?**
- **It's explainable ?**
- **If no, it's a bug ?**

Thanks for your patience !

Comment: I think, it is like UV maps not working with volumetric shaders, data just belongs to surface domain and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

I am using geometry nodes mesh for Volumetric and discovered that the GN mesh was offset so I had to add some vector offset in GN to correct the texture. Maybe thats your issue too?